# Calculate the power spectral density of a Markov chain

Tags: symbolic, time-series, markov-chains

I would like to calculate the symbolic power spectral density of a two state Markov process with a symbolic transition matrix characterised by two parameters.

I have tried the code below, but it doesn't seem to work. Any help is much appreciated!

```
M = {{1 - pdw, pdw}, {pwd, 1 - pwd}}
P  = DiscreteMarkovProcess[{1, 0}, M]
PowerSpectralDensity[P, omega]
```